# DataTables - move tr row and "reload" table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use DataTable with pagination (10 records per page). I allow my users to change the position of rows in this datatable and when table has 10 records or low - there is no problem. The problem is when pagination is in action (so when on page is more than 10 rows). Then I can't move for example second tr row on new position - 12'th.

Example:

before:

> Row1
>
> **Row2**
>
> ...
>
> Row12
>
> Row 13

After:

> Row1
>
> Row3
>
> ...
>
> Row11
>
> **Row2**
>
> Row 12
>
> Row13

How I can do it with Datatables and with using pagination?

Now I do it in that way:

```
$('#tr_row12').insertBefore('#tr_row2');
```

but when pagination is in action, the #tr_row12 is on the next page (so it doesn't exist on 1'th page of pagination) of pagination and it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use [RowReorder](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/) extension with scrolling enabled, please see [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/scroll.html).